# Django: CSS and Images (Static Files) loaded successfully but not applied

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Django Dev Server and trying to test some templates I've made. When I visit addresses, I can see from the server prompt that CSS and images are loaded, but when I'm looking in a browser it is not applied. I'm also using Bootstrap and strangely enough, it does get applied.

I would really like some help. I've seen (and implemented) the solution from various other threads with no avail. Please Help!

Threads I've seen:

[Django -- Can't get static CSS files to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574759/django-cant-get-static-css-files-to-load)

[CSS loaded but not applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600512/css-loaded-but-not-applied)

[Django Static Files - CSS File Won't Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878455/django-static-files-css-file-wont-load)

[Django CSS Attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306442/django-css-attachment)

[Django - CSS problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792243/django-css-problems)

[CSS loaded but empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38527133/css-loaded-but-empty)

Comment: in your browser open the source view of the page and click the links of your css. what you get?

Comment: It has the correct href, but it returns a Django Debug page saying stylesheet.css' not found. I think that the server does locate the file though, because before, when I didn't have the Django pointing to the right folder to look for my static files, it return a "Not Found" in the prompt.

Comment: Okay, not sure what I did wrong but, I restructured the path of my where my static files are to look like myapp/static/myapp/stylesheet.css, and I got the CSS to load.

It's a bit odd to me though that this solved it, because I had set the finder to look in the folder where I originally had my static files. It kinda scary how inflexible things seem to be.

Comment: A follow up question:

I am using both my own CSS and Bootstrap. My personal CSS seems to be being overwritten by Bootstrap CSS. How do I set the priority of how the CSS is used so that my CSS overwrites the Bootstrap?

Comment: load your css after the bootstrap.css . It is because of the logic ` x = 3; x = 5;` this gives x = 5. you get this.

Answer (score 2):

Moving the CSS after bootstrap worked for me.

Like this

`<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/checkout.css' %}">`